# Macbook pro dead battery can't boot

Tags: macbook-pro

Macbook pro show dead battery symbol can't boot.  This is late 2014 retina model.  So my question is short of installing new battery you can never boot this laptop?  Assuming the battery is dead.

More detail.  When I plug in the charger and try to boot it will show this symbol but no matter how long I charge it it still shows this symbol when I try to boot it won't boot.

[image]

Comment: I've changed the battery of a mid 2014 MacBook Pro (there is no "late 2014") and could boot whilst it had no battery.  It only was a lot slower because of it.

Comment: How can it show a dead battery symbol, if it can't boot..? Have you tried booting with a power cable? None of my (seven) Macbook Pro models have batteries and they all boot fine. Maybe take the battery out. A swollen battery *will* damage and distort the touch pad.

Comment: You should be able to boot it, but you need to supply loads more info about what's going on. Where do you see this 'dead battery' sign? What happens when you try to boot? A MacBook Pro with no battery will throttle the CPU significantly. This is a deliberate power management design, because the power cable does not have the power to run the CPU at full tilt. The battery powers the computer, the cable charges the battery.

Comment: [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+Battery+Replacement/27832) offers a guide on how to disconnect the battery (and to replace it).

Comment: @slartibartfast yes I know but that is last resort I'm asking if this can be booted without replacing battery.